# How to check ping failure in logs/event viewer?

Tags: windows, wireless-networking, ping, events, viewer

Ping had failed(Request timed out) to a target windows 7 system(192.168.0.31) continuously (continuous timed outs) for a time period of one minute.

In the target system 192.168.0.31(windows server 2008), how to check/identify related ping lost logs in "event viewer" (or if any) regarding the ping failure?

Comment: Welcome at SuperUser. Please specify the _failed_ state: `Request timed out` message or `Destination host unreachable` reply or another? And what the _for one minute_ stands for? One minute of good answer(s) and then failure or opposite results? (_Please do not reply in comment; improve your question by using [edit] link rather_).

Answer (score 1):

I think you are using Windows target machine. You can create a rule to log in Windows firewall for incoming ICMP request.

Use the below microsoft link how to configure the rule with log

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff428145%28v=ws.10%29.aspx

Also you can use third party utilities & sniffing tools.